# Лучшие способы и ресурсы для обучения

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-дизайн

Реквестирую хорошие ресурсы и способы обучения веб-разработке с нуля
Фулл стек

Comment: https://metanit.com/ Для начала самое оно. Потом в документацию)

Comment: Учебники русского языка и хороших манер для начала.